# Aurelia: How to bind App method in Navbar?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I've spent some time trying get the wiring for this working properly and can't. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The best reference I've found for this issue so far is [Aurelia Binding Click Trigger in Nav Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191451/aurelia-binding-click-trigger-in-nav-bar/36522782). I tried that approach but am still getting the same error:

Uncaught Error: authenticate is not a function(…) in aurelia-binding.js:1965 (getFunction)

Here's what my setup looks like:

nav-bar.html

```
<template bindable="router, authenticate">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                <span>${router.title}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation | authFilter: authenticated" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main.in" href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul if.bind="authenticated" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>${userName}</li>
                <li><a href="/#/logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul if.bind="!authenticated" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a id="loginLink" click.trigger="authenticate()">Login</a></li>
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="loader" if.bind="router.isNavigating">
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

app.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./views/shared/nav-bar.html"></require>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <nav-bar router.bind="router" authenticate.call="authenticate()"></nav-bar>
    <div class="page-host">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

app.ts

```
import {inject, computedFrom} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router'
import {AuthService, AuthenticateStep} from 'aurelia-authentication';
import {log} from "./services/log";

@inject(AuthService)
export class App {

   authService: AuthService;
   router: Router;
   userName: string;

   constructor(auth) {
      this.authService = auth;
   }

  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
  config.title = 'AppName';
  config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthenticateStep);

  config.map([
     { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: 'views/welcome', nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
     { route: "orgTypes", name: "orgTypes", moduleId: "views/orgTypes", nav: true, auth: true, title: "Organization Types" },
     { route: "credits", name: "credits", moduleId: "views/credits", nav: true, auth: true, title: "Application Credits" }
  ]);

  this.router = router;
   }

   authenticate() {
   return this.authService.authenticate('identityServer')
     .then((response) => {
        log.info("login successful");
     });
   };


   @computedFrom('authService.authenticated')
   get authenticated() {
      return this.authService.authenticated;

   }

}
```

What is the proper setup to get a method in the App VM to bind in a subview?

Edit 1: Following FabioLuz second comment.

Comment: You have declared `authenticate` bindable property but you are using `loginLink.call="authenticate()"`, even if loginLink was correct, the binding declaration should be `login-link.call="authenticate()"`

Comment: @FabioLuz Tried that but no joy. loginLink is the id of the element that needs binding, where would I find how this should be defined? Thanks!

Comment: in app.html, try `authenticate.call="authenticate()"` and in nav-bar.html try `click.trigger="authenticate()"`

Comment: @FabioLuz tried that, still no joy. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Fabio has suggested is valid and should be working. You might have other issues preventing it from functioning.

Can you check it by simplifying `App.authenticate()` like this? 
Just to rule out possible errors of underlying layer.

```js
authenticate() {
  log.info("login successful");
}
```

**Another guess:**

Is `./services/log` a static object? Assuming it is not, injection might be missing for it.

Since you are using TypeScript, `autoinject` might help you to avoid similar pitfalls.

```js
import {autoinject, computedFrom} from "aurelia-framework";
import {AuthService, AuthenticateStep} from 'aurelia-authentication';
import {log} from "./services/log";

@autoinject()
export class App {

  authService: AuthService;
  logger: log;

  constructor(auth: AuthService, logger: log) {
    this.authService = auth;
    this.logger = logger;
  }
}
```

---

> What is the proper setup to get a method in the App VM to bind in a subview?

I know 3 possible solutions to achieve that (there may be more). I've created a gist showing these in action.

https://gist.run/?id=b9e8fee11e338e08bc5da7d4df68e2db

Use the dropdown to switch between navbar implementations. :)

#### 1. HTML Only Element + `bindables`

This is your current scenario. See `nav-bar-function.html` in the demo.

#### 2. `<compose>` + inheritance

Composition can be useful for some dynamic scenarios, but try not to overuse it. [[Blog post]](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-custom-element-vs-compose/)

When no model is provided, composed element inherits parent's viewmodel context.

Normally I would not recommend using it in your case. However, considering your issues with Solution 1., you could use this option for debug purposes. If you get the same error with `<compose>` as well, you may have a problem with `App.authenticate()` function itself.

Try it out in your solution by replacing

`<nav-bar router.bind="router" authenticate.call="authenticate()"></nav-bar>`

with

`<compose view="./nav-bar.html"></compose>`

This way, `nav-bar.html` behaves as a part of `App` component. See `nav-bar-compose.html` in the demo.

#### 3. Custom Element + EventAggregator

You can use pub/sub communication between components* to avoid tight-coupling. Related SO answer: [[Accessing Custom Component Data/Methods]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670825/accessing-custom-component-data-methods/39673984#39673984), and [[Docs]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/10)

*components: custom elements with viewmodel classes

---

I hope it will help! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough walk through and sample. It helped me get past the binding issue!

Comment: Fantastic, I'm happy that it helped you!